# How to calculate: $\frac{1}{2}log_2(⁡(2πe)^2(σ^2+N_a))+\frac{1}{2}log_2(⁡(2πe)^2(σ^2+N_b))-log_2((2πe)^2|K_y |)$

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution, determinant

$K_y$ has the form:

$$Ky \sim \left(0, \left[\begin{matrix}σ^2+N_a & σ^2 \\ σ^2 & σ^2+N_b\end{matrix}\right]\right)$$

So the determinant $|K_y |$ is: $N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2$

Which leads to:

$$\frac{1}{2}log_2⁡((2πe)^2(σ^2+N_a))+\frac{1}{2}log_2(⁡(2πe)^2(σ^2+N_b))-log_2((2πe)^2(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2))$$

My final result is expected to be:

$$\frac{1}{2}log_2(1+\frac{σ^2}{N_a+N_b+\frac{N_aN_b}{σ^2}})$$

But I cannot find the last steps. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean  $$\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡((2πe)^2(σ^2+N_a))+\frac{1}{2}\log_2(⁡(2πe)^2(σ^2+N_b))-\log_2((2πe)^2|K_y |)?$$ (Note the added parentheses)

Comment: @helloworld112358 yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the form from my comment, and starting with: $$\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡((2πe)^2(σ^2+N_a))+\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡((2πe)^2(σ^2+N_b))-\log_2((2πe)^2(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2))$$

We apply the rules $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$, $\log(a)-\log(b)=\log(a/b)$, and $\log(a^x)=x\log(a)$.

Using the first and the third rule, we combine the first two terms, and pull a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ out in front of the third term:

$$\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡((2\pi e)^4(\sigma^2+N_a)(\sigma^2+N_b))-\frac{1}{2}\log_2((2πe)^4(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2)$$

Now we apply the second rule:

$$\frac{1}{2}log_2⁡\left(\frac{(\sigma^2+N_a)(\sigma^2+N_b)}{(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2}\right)$$

We can simplify the inside as follows:

$$\frac{(\sigma^2+N_a)(\sigma^2+N_b)}{(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2}=\frac{\sigma^4+(N_a+N_b)\sigma^2+N_aN_b}{(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2}=\frac{1+\frac{\sigma^4}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}=\frac{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{\frac{N_a N_b}{\sigma^2}+N_a+N_b}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}$$

This isn't quite what you were looking for - we can write it in this form: 
$$\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡\left(\frac{1+\frac{\sigma^2}{\frac{N_a N_b}{\sigma^2}+N_a+N_b}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log_2⁡\left(1+\frac{\sigma^2}{\frac{N_a N_b}{\sigma^2}+N_a+N_b}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log_2(|K_y|)$$

I believe it would work out as desired if it were $\sqrt{|K_y|}$.

Comment: How do you get the second equality:

$$\frac{\sigma^4+(N_a+N_b)\sigma^2+N_aN_b}{(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2}=\frac{1+\frac{\sigma^4}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}$$

Comment: $$\frac{\sigma^4+(N_a+N_b)\sigma^2+N_aN_b}{(N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2)^2}=\frac{\frac{\sigma^4+(N_a+N_b)\sigma^2+N_aN_b}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}=\frac{\frac{(N_a+N_b)\sigma^2+N_aN_b}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}+\frac{\sigma^4}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}=\frac{1+\frac{\sigma^4}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}}{N_a N_b+N_a σ^2+N_b σ^2}$$